# Application getting website response

Tags: java, android, eclipse

net developer and dont know about android. could you please help me to fix this code

> Exception: android.os.networkmainthreadException on
>   client.execute(get1)

```
        try
        {

            HttpGet  get1 = new HttpGet ("http://www.google.com/");
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();            
            HttpResponse response =   client.execute(get1);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        }
        catch(Exception e  )
        {
            urlview.setText( "hi bug"+ e.toString());               
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing network operation on UI thread which in not allowed in android version >=3.0 So use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)